Passing ViewModel to View
I have a view model:
@MainActor public class TestViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [String: [String]]
    
    init() {
        self.data = ["a": ["a1", "a2"]]
    }
}

There is a nested view which uses this data:
struct ContainerView: View {
    @Binding var data: [String: [String]]
    
    var body: some View {
        List() {
            ForEach(data.keys.sorted(), id: \.self){ key in
                Text(key)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = TestViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ContainerView(
            data: $viewModel.data
        )
    }
}

This works as expected.
But say I have a lot of different kinds of published data. It would be nice if I could simply pass the view model itself, which I actually can do:
struct ContainerView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TestViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List() {
            ForEach($viewModel.data.keys.sorted(), id: \.self){ key in
                Text(key)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = TestViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ContainerView(
            viewModel: viewModel
        )
    }
}

This works fine for most of the use cases of ViewModel within ContainerView (which I have left out for brevity), but not for this one. In the ForEach, I get these errors:

Cannot assign to property: 'keys' is a get-only property


Cannot call value of non-function type 'Binding<() -> [Dictionary<String, [String]>.Keys.Element]>' (aka 'Binding<() -> Array>')


Dynamic key path member lookup cannot refer to instance method 'sorted()'

What is going on here?

viewModel.data is mutable, but viewModel.data.keys is read-only. When you're passing $viewModel.data.keys that's a Binding and Binding expects to write to the path where the variable is in, in this case viewModel.data.keys, which is read-only.

But isn't it also a binding in the first case? Any where in the ForEach is there any attempt to write to the property (doesn't .sorted() just read)?

I think not. With binding you use this API: ForEach(Binding<MutableCollection & RandomAccessCollection>, id: KeyPath<C.Element, _>) { Binding<C.Element> -> _}. With the first you are accessing this: ForEach(RandomAccessCollection, content: (Identifiable) -> View)

Why do you want to use a Binding ? just use "ForEach(viewModel.data.keys.sorted()". If you want to modify a ky or the content of data, this is the job of the ViewModel and as you get it as an ObservedObject there is no problem.

@PtitXav If you post an answer, I can accept it.

Just use "ForEach(viewModel.data.keys.sorted()
If you want to modify a ky or the content of data, this is the job of the ViewModel and as you get it as an ObservedObject there is no problem.
@MainActor public class TestViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [String: [String]]
    
    init() {
        self.data = ["a": ["a1", "a2"]]
    }

    // to update data
    func updateData(for key: String, strings: [String]) {
        self.data[key] = strings
    }

    // to add data
    func addData(for key: String, strings: [String]) {
        self.data[key] = strings
    }
}

struct ContainerView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TestViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List() {
            Button("add key b") {
                viewModel.addData(for: "b", strings: ["b1", "b2"])
            }
            Button("update key b") {
                viewModel.addData(for: "b", strings: ["b3", "b4"])
            }
            Button("add key c") {
                viewModel.addData(for: "c", strings: ["c1", "c2"])
            }
            ForEach(viewModel.data.keys.sorted(), id: \.self){ key in
                let strings = viewModel.data[key]!.joined(separator: "-")
                Text(key + "=" + strings)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = TestViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ContainerView(
            viewModel: viewModel
        )
    }
}

